# Defining different parameter value for simulation and synthesis

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, synplify

I'm using systemVerilog and I have a package that holds some of my modules parameter values (for example `parameter SPI_RATE = 2_000_000;`). Is there any way I can set one value for simulation and a different one for synthesis? (I'm using ModelSim).
For example I would like something like:

```
if(IN_SIM) begin
parameter SPI_RATE = 2_000_000;
end
else begin
parameter SPI_RATE = 1_000_000;
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: aren't you heading to verification/synthesis mismatch wit this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. SystemVerilog supports *conditional compiler directives* such as `` `ifdef ``, `` `ifndef ``, `` `else ``, `` `elsif ``, and `` `endif ``. Note that those directives are using a *grave accent* (ASCII 0x60) and not a normal apostrophe (ASCII 0x27).

Furthermore, most synthesis tools support the macro identifier `SYNTHESIS`. So, you could do the following:

```
`ifdef SYNTHESIS
  parameter SPI_RATE = 1_000_000;
`else
  parameter SPI_RATE = 2_000_000;    
`endif
```

Comment: It sounds exactly like what I meant! :) Thanks!
I've searched a bit and haven't found anything like this in Synopsys synplify pro, have any idea how it may be called there?

Comment: Take a look in the "Synopsys FPGA Synthesis Language Support Reference Manual" and search for "synthesis macro". The manual states that Synplify Pro supports the `SYNTHESIS` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set a macro from the command line in any simulation using the `+define` plusarg, eg:

```
+define+SPI_RATE=2_000_000
```

Then somewhere in your code, you can say

```
parameter SPI_RATE = `SPI_RATE;
```

And in your synthesiser there will be a mechanism for setting the value of a macro: read the instructions for your synthesiser.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO -

Using the first answer

`ifdef SYNTHESIS

is much preferred over the 3rd answer

/* synthesis translate_off */

The last form is a variation of /* synopsys translate_off */, which was unique to one synthesis tool.

The macro SYNTHESIS has been in common use for more than a decade, and should be defined by any synthesis tool, without any extra command line options.

If you want to run equivalence checking (rtl vs gate level netlist), you will probably need to define the SYNTHESIS macro by the method recommended for that equivalence tool.

Comment: Please don't refer answers by their sequence as that can vary

Comment: Saad, thanks. I realized that after I posted.

Answer (score -2):

With Synplify Pro, you can use the /*synthesis translate_off */ /*synthesis translate_off */ to accomplish this, a similar construct is usable in VHDL with appropriate syntax/comment changes. Xilinx Vivado uses // synthesis translate_off and // synthesis translate_on

```
const logic IN_SIM = 1'b0
/*synthesis translate_off */
    || 1'b1
/*synthesis translate_on */
    ;
```

The advantage of this construct is that it doesn't require any external scripting changes.

Comment: You should avoid using any translation directives. It causes sim/synth mismatches. Besides this solution is not good for non-0  parameter and is just a hack.

Comment: @Serge did you read the question?  That is the whole point, to produce different behaviour in simulation and synthesis, it can be used to produce any number you desire using the simple if else OP used in his code

Comment: yes, i did. OP has a bad methodology decision. It is a bad methodology to use synthesis directives in any case.  It is also a programming hack in your case.