# What logic will be created if variables in the sensitivity list are missing

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

This was an interview question asked by a top 10 company of US.

Code 1:

```
always @(a or b or sel) begin 
  if (sel == 1)
  c = a; 
  else if (sel == 0) 
  c =b; 
end
```

This will create a mux.

Code 2: Now "SEL" is removed from sensitivity. Will it still create mux?
For  the code below? If not, what logic will be created?

```
always @(a or b) begin 
  if (sel == 1)
  c = a; 
  else if (sel == 0) 
  c =b; 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will still synthesize to a multiplexer<sup>1</sup>. A synthesis tool will interpret this RTL as if the sensitivity list were complete.

*However*, a large issue here arises because you will see different behaviour in your RTL simulations compared to the gate-level simulations/the actual silicon. In your RTL simulation, `c` will *only* change if `a` or `b` change. If only the select-signal `sel` of the multiplexer changes, your output `c` will not change in RTL simulations.

When intending to create combinatorial logic, it is generally advisable to use

```
always @(*)
```

or

```
always_comb
```

if you can use SystemVerilog. This has the advantage that you never run into sensitivity-list related simulation/synthesis mismatches. The latter keyword furthermore has the advantage that you explicitly tell tools that you want to create combinatorial logic (rather than unintended latches, for example).

Finally: Mills & Cummings wrote a great paper on [RTL Coding Styles That Yield Simulation and Synthesis Mismatches](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf). This issue, among many others, is described here very well. I can greatly recommend to take a look at this paper!

---

### Bonus: X-Propagation and simulation mismatches with actual silicon

As you indicated in your comment, you were wondering what would happen is `sel === 1'bx`. To better understand this matter, I highly recommend reading [I'm  Still In Love With My X!](https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-DVCon_In-love-with-my-X_paper.pdf) by Stuart Sutherland. I will give a very brief summary on your particular example here.

Conditional blocks in SystemVerilog are prone to X-optimism, which is defined in the aforementioned paper as:

> X-optimism  has  been  defined  [...]  as  any  time  simulation converts an X value on the input to an operation or logic gate into a 0 or 1 on the output. [...] SystemVerilog  can  be  overly  optimistic,  meaning  an  X  propagates as a 0 or 1 in simulation when actual silicon is still  ambiguous.

When looking at your code, we will see that an `sel === 1'bx` will *not* propagate to `c`. Rather, the simulator will hold the previous value of `c` and mimic a latch. This is overly X-optimistic and is a simulation mismatch with actual silicon, since the select line will not be X here: a signal is either 1 or 0. In other words, this will *not* be a latch in silicon!

One solution *could* be to make the multiplexer X-pessimistic in simulation, so that we would detect this undetermined state. To do so, we assign X to `c` when `sel` is neither 0, nor 1:

```
always_comb
    if (sel)
        c = a; 
    else if (!sel) 
        c = b; 
`ifndef SYNTHESIS // see footnote 2
    else
        c = 'x;
`endif
```

This has the problem, however, that it is overly pessimistic. When both `a` and `b` have the same value, we would unambiguously know what value `c` would have in actual silicon (regardless of the value of `sel`).

The aformentioned paper gives the conditional operator (`? :`) as a possible solution:

> `condition ? expression1 : expression2;`
>
> If the condition evaluates to unknown, the operator does a bit-by-bit comparison of the values of expression1 and expression2. For each bit position, if that bit is 0 in both expressions, then a 0 is returned for that bit. If both bits are  1,  a  1  is  returned.  If  the  corresponding  bits  in  each  expression are different, or Z, or X, then an X is returned for that bit

So, by using the code below, we would have a compromise between the two aforementioned solutions:

```
always_comb
    c = sel ? a : b;
```

The downside here is that the conditional operator is not suited for more complex expressions.

The three approaches summarized:

```
╭───────────╥─────────────────────────────────────────────────╮      
│   input   ║                     sel(t)                      │
├───╥───╥───╫────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬─────────┤
│sel║ a ║ b ║ optimistic │ pessimistic │ compromise │ silicon │
╞═══╬═══╬═══╬════════════╪═════════════╡════════════╪═════════╡
│ X ║ 0 ║ 0 ║  sel(t-1)  │      X      │     0      │    0    │
│ X ║ 0 ║ 1 ║  sel(t-1)  │      X      │     X      │   0/1   │
│ X ║ 1 ║ 0 ║  sel(t-1)  │      X      │     X      │   0/1   │
│ X ║ 1 ║ 1 ║  sel(t-1)  │      X      │     1      │    1    │
└───╨───╨───╨────────────┴─────────────┘────────────┴─────────┘
```

In his paper, Sutherland gives another solution with which I agree: It is best to use assertions to detect design issues which cause X, instead of letting X propagate through the design and spending a lot of time finding the root cause. For your particular code, this could look like this:

```
always_comb
begin
    assert (!$isknown(sel))
    else $error("sel = X!");

    if (sel)
        c = a; 
    else if (!sel) 
        c = b; 
 end
```

---

<sup>1: I assume here that `sel` is a 1-bit signal. Otherwise, you would end up with a latch</sup>

<sup>2: [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946670/defining-different-parameter-value-for-simulation-and-synthesis/60947273#60947273) for some more information on the `SYNTHESIS` macro identifier.</sup>

Comment: A follow up question on it: What will be the value of output 'c' if the select line was 'X'. ?

Comment: For simulation , this won't implement a multiplexer, but a latch. sel can be Z or X as well.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: You are right, I overlooked the `else if` rather than an `else`. I will enhance my answer later to add some more information on this. @Devashree Dagli: you might be interested in this (pretty good) SNUG paper on x-propagation: https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-DVCon_In-love-with-my-X_paper.pdf

Comment: @DevashreeDagli, I've updated my answer with some more information on what will happen when the select line is X in simulations.